# How to remove delay when i dynamic creating MovieClip

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I would like simulate road in my game, and for this i use road's lanes and traffic, lanes and traffic dynamic created like this

```
if(roadlineTimer-- == 0){
        roadlineTimer = 30;
        newRoadline = new Roadline();
        newRoadline.x = 0;
        newRoadline.y = 0;
        newRoadline.speed = 3;
        roadlines.push(newRoadline);
        addChildAt(newRoadline,numChildren-1);
    }
```

But when complile and run this code. I have visible delays. My lane likes as rectangle and have own class. How I can optimize this code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to tell by just this snippet alone, but a big part of the delay could be object instantiation (new Roadline()), because that is a very expensive operation (CPU-wise). You can eliminate it if you create the max number of Roadlines before the start, and then just re-use them as the need arises.

Google 'object pool' for some in-depth discussion, and you may even stumble upon some ready-made flash solutions (personally, I use object pool from http://lab.polygonal.de/2008/06/18/using-object-pools/)

Answer (score 1):

it looks like the problem is elsewhere , there's not enough here to go by...

on the other hand , if you're going to do this

```
addChildAt(newRoadline,numChildren-1);
```

you may as well do this

```
addChild(newRoadline);
```

although i doubt this will solve your delay problem